# Stata ANOVA Interaction term differences

Tags: anova, interaction, stata

The following two statements produce different results.

```
/* DV: "price" e.g., from 0 to 100 */
/* IV: "treatmentA", "treatmentB" both binary variables */

/* statement 1 */
anova price treatmentA##treatmentB

/* statement 2 */    
generate A_x_B = treatmentA * treatmentB
anova price treatmentA treatmentB A_x_B
```

Do the two statements not represent the same model?

Any suggestions, why generating an interaction term by myself and including it into an ANOVA produces different results than using the built-in option to include interaction terms?

edit:
some additional output:

```
. anova price treatmentA##treatmentB

                           Number of obs =    2160     R-squared     =  0.0481
                           Root MSE      = 3.62039     Adj R-squared =  0.0468

                  Source |  Partial SS    df       MS           F     Prob > F
    ---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Model |  1427.66343     3  475.887809      36.31     0.0000
                         |
              treatmentA |  590.372454     1  590.372454      45.04     0.0000
              treatmentB |  786.261343     1  786.261343      59.99     0.0000
    treatmentA#treatme~B |  258.622454     1  258.622454      19.73     0.0000
                         |
                Residual |  28259.1958  2156  13.1072337   
    ---------------------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Total |  29686.8593  2159  13.7502822   

 . generate A_x_B = treatmentA * treatmentB    
 . anova price treatmentA treatmentB A_x_B

                           Number of obs =    2160     R-squared     =  0.0481
                           Root MSE      = 3.62039     Adj R-squared =  0.0468

                  Source |  Partial SS    df       MS           F     Prob > F
             ------------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Model |  1427.66343     3  475.887809      36.31     0.0000
                         |
              treatmentA |       33.75     1       33.75       2.57     0.1087
              treatmentB |  730.034722     1  730.034722      55.70     0.0000
                   A_x_B |  258.622454     1  258.622454      19.73     0.0000
                         |
                Residual |  28259.1958  2156  13.1072337   
             ------------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Total |  29686.8593  2159  13.7502822
```

Comment: How different are we talking?

Comment: The output is way different. Although not the overall result but individual variables

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `A_x_B` is generated and stored as a float (7 decimal places more-or-less), by your command, but using the built in option to generate an interation term, would create a double, thus is evaluated exactly (or at least to double accuracy).

Comment: The differences don't look (to me) like differences due to float point precision, since the interaction term itself is the same. Other variables differ.

Comment: noted, this is weird, I'll have a look and get back